# Hyper-V Virtual Switch Multiple Static IP

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v, network-adapter

I have a Hyper-V VM in a Windows 10 host laptop, host machine has one NIC with 2 static IP's set (10.0.10.1 and 10.0.200.1). From the host machine I can able to ping the nodes in 10.0.10.x and 10.0.200.x, but from the Hyper VM I can able to ping only the node in 10.0.10.x not from 10.0.200.x.

Any help on this please.

Comment: If you’re using bridged networking, simply add IPs on both subnets to the VM? Like you did on the host.

Comment: I have created a external virtual switch and linked it to the host's NIC in the hyper-v, not using any bridged networking.

Comment: That _is_ bridged networking...

Comment: That worked actually. Thanks